# Reference request: Über das Zentrum einer Kategorie

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

I would like to know the results proven in the following paper:

- R-E. Hoffmann, *Über das Zentrum einer Kategorie*, Mathematische Nachrichten 68 (1), 299-306, 1975

One can see the first page at [the publisher](https://doi.org/10.1002/mana.19750680122).

Does anyone have access and can state the results here?

Comment: https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1002/mana.19750680122

Comment: Thanks @KevinArlin! I didn't know this site. Do you want to post this as a short answer? Then I can mark this as answered.

Comment: Sure. I've posted the DOI rather than the SciHub link as SciHub's legal status in many jurisdictions encourages link rot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOI of this article is sufficient to access it via websites like SciHub, assuming this is legal in your jurisdiction or you don't care to respect Springer's right to near-perpetual profits on intellectual work: https://doi.org/10.1002/mana.19750680122

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe you also have an idea for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4580187/reference-request-lindners-thesis-on-morita-equivalence ?