# Reference request: Lindner's thesis on Morita equivalence

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, enriched-category-theory, morita-equivalence

I would like to know the contents or at least the main results of the following thesis, which has been cited in other category theory papers:

H. Lindner, *Morita-Äquivalenz von Kategorien über einer geschlossenen Kategorie*, Dissertation, Düsseldorf, 1973

There is an English paper by the same author with a similar name [here](https://eudml.org/doc/91143), but I assume that this is a much shorter version (in particular it doesn't have the result I am looking for which is supposed to be in the thesis).

Can anybody here post a summary perhaps?

Comment: I can't find any reason to believe that this dissertation exists online anywhere, including an attempt to search on Düsseldorf's online document server, though I don't read German so I may not be using it well. If I'm correct that it's never been scanned, which seems quite likely a priori, then your best bet would probably be to go to Düsseldorf, where they'll have a copy on deposit, or at least try an interlibrary loan (but it sounds like you may not have access to an academic library anymore.)

Comment: There also seem to be only three known citations to this dissertation, all from the '70s, two of which are "confers" and one of which is merely a bibliographic mention.

Comment: There are copies in Düsseldorf, Köln and Kaiserslautern (if I read the information in "http://193.30.112.134/F/X213YU7V5PIKGELHAUA4RHVI2M4RUECBDLGKSTJLJQSEYDM7SE-06019?func=full-set-set&set_number=131979&set_entry=000004&format=999" correctly).

Comment: This is great. So perhaps someone from these universities can help here. :-)

Comment: What's so interesting about Morita equivalence anyway?

Comment: If you email the library at Düsseldorf, one of the librarians might be happy to scan a copy of the thesis for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: ![enter image description here]

After some searching on the web, it appears that such thesis was a **speech** held by Lindner in 1973.

As you can see [here](http://archive.numdam.org/article/CTGDC_1974__15_4_377_0.pdf), the *Morita Equivalences of Enriched Categories* by Harald LINDNER was a "Conférence donnée au Colloque d’Amiens (1973)", which means a "Lecture given at the Amiens Colloquium (1973)". 
Thus, even if the English  version is dated 1974, it is a translation of the abovementioned speech held in 1973 (the *Dissertation* the German title is pointing out).

Furthermore, if you look at the end of the paper, it was redacted and published by the Maths institute of the University of Dusseldorf:

[image]

in agreement with the reference that we have.

In brief, we are in front of a translation of the original speech. We may read a summary of the paper [here](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0319.18006), too.

Comment: Thank you very much for this research.

Comment: Certainly there was a talk given by Lindner in 1973, but how do you conclude from this observation that the German reference refers to the talk? It seems unlikely to me that the transcript of a talk would be long enough to warrant the description "dissertation".

Comment: @varkor Well, also the title is the same, and the publisher too

Comment: I think it is not uncommon for authors in mathematics to publish an abridged version of a thesis under the same name (as much as this might seem bad practice).

Comment: Furthermore, if Lindner were to give a talk about a dissertation, it is very likely he would use the same name for the talk. I don't see how this addresses Martin's original reservations about the English version of the paper: in particular, that the English version does not contain results that are supposed to be included in the dissertation.

Comment: The English paper refers to the talk itself

Comment: I agree that the English paper appears to be a transcription/elaboration of the talk given in Amiens, but I am not so eager to conclude that the German paper is of the same nature.

Comment: @varkor I see the point. Consider also that if the paper is meant as an extract from the original Dissertation or as a summary, however there is no reference to such dissertation in the bibliography. I agree though that we cannot be 100% sure, I just expressed what it seemed to me likely based on the available data. I went on searching, but could not find otherwise evidence. If something comes up, I will for sure update the answer

Comment: Lindner must have written a PhD thesis, and it would not be surprising to be on this topic.